# Create a glue job that splits an array into rows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I currently have data arriving from Firehose into an Athena table. When I view the data it is an array of JSON. Is it possible to use a glue job to split the arrays into separate rows so each row is its own JSON log.

For example: Data arriving
[{"a":"test1", "b":"success"},{"a":"test2", "b":"success"}]

What the glue job should change it to:
{"a":"test1", "b":"success"}
{"a":"test2", "b":"success"}

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily with the [explode function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) of pyspark.

You just need to convert your DynamicFrame to a DataFrame, by calling the `.toDF()` function on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the relationalize method of Glue, it does wonder for nested structures.
You can go through the examples here [Relationalize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html)